# How can I use variables in target file paths for org capture templates?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, config

I use emacs on a few different machines which unfortunately don't have the same file structure, but I want to share my config among them as much as possible. All machines have a ".../org/" folder which is synchronized with syncthing. I want to set up my capture templates to build their target file paths from a variable set per-machine which points to that org folder, instead of manually editing each template's target to be the full path to each file.

I have put this code in my init.el:

```
(setq lk/org-file-path "~/../../Documents/org/")

(setq org-capture-templates
    '(("t" "tasks / Projects")
     ("tt" "task" entry (file+olp (concat lk/org-file-path "Tasks.org") "Inbox")
      "* TODO %?\n %U\n %a\n %i" :empty-lines 1)
    ...
    ))
```

Trying to capture with this template gives the error "Invalid file location: nil". But running `(concat lk/org-file-path "Tasks.org")` in scratch results in "~/../../Documents/org/Tasks.org", and putting that string in place of the concat in the template definition allows the template to successfully run and save my input in the correct file.

How can I work around this?